# Saving attached data in ObjectBox

Tags: android, objectbox

There is a class structure similar to this:

```
@Entity
public class A
{public ToOne<B> b;}

@Entity
public class B{public ToOne<C> с;}

@Entity
public class C{public ToOne<D> d;}

@Entity
public class D{}
```

It is filled like this:

```
ArrayList<A> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
C с = new C();
D d = new D();
getStore().boxFor(C).attach(c);
c.d.setTarget(d);
getStore().boxFor(B).attach(b);
b.c.setTarget(c);
getStore().boxFor(A).attach(a);
a.b.setTarget(b);
}

getStore().boxFor(A).putAll(list);
```

And it reads like this:

```
ArrayList<A> list2 = getStore().boxFor(A).getAll();
//list2.get(0).b.getTarget() is empty
```

The problem is that after reading the second level is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `applyChangesToDb()`.
Docs: https://docs.objectbox.io/relations